# Question regarding Events in John Skeet's book C# in Depth

Tags: c#, events

I'm studying C# Events [on this link](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) and am a little lost on when the following code is called in the context of Main()

```
/// <summary>
/// Raises the SomeEvent event
/// </summary>
protected virtual OnSomeEvent(EventArgs e)
{
    SomeEventHandler handler;
    lock (someEventLock)
    {
        handler = someEvent;
    }
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler (this, e);
    }
}
```

It's code that is right above the sentence

> "You could use a single lock for all your events"

Question:

How or when does "OnSomeEvent" get called?  I'm not asking about variable locking (as-is the context of the code sample) rather, I'm asking when does the `protected virtual` method pasted above get called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class calls `OnSomeEvent` when it wants to fire off the event.

Comment: Something like   OnSomeEvent(new EventArgs())

Comment: Exactly like you'd call any other function. `OnSomeEvent(new EventArgs());`

Comment: The "virtual" part just means "subclasses can override this".

Comment: The book has a section on "Calling Delegates", I suppose what I need is a small section on "Calling Events" to get through my head.  Who calls events, and why?  How is the event parameter constructed?

Comment: The class "calls events" when it wants to signal that event; ie: when a property's value's changed, the property setter might trigger a ValueChanged event or something.  Only the class should be calling event delegates, and a common pattern is to see an OnValueChanged(...) method raising a ValueChanged event.

Comment: And "the class" that fires the event is (1) the class that contains the event or (2) a different class that instantiates a class, and then calls instanceObject.event?

Comment: Got it: I see a full example, even with custom event args here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx   Thanks (everyone) for your help on this n00b topic!

Comment: The class that fires the event is the class that contains the event.  Everyone else only subscribes or unsubscribes to the event, and supplies a delegate to run when the event is fired by the class.

Comment: Makes total sense now.  Thanks cHao!